# Returning an object of the same type as the function's caller

Tags: java, generics, return-type

I have two classes, one which extends the other. Most of the functions in the parent class return either itself (after modifying the object that called the function) or a new object of the same type. The child class is supposed to share these functions, however its should return an object of the child type.

The obvious solution to this issue is to just override every function and convert them into an object of the child type, but I don't want to do this every time I make a child class.

I did some searching and found some solutions using generic functions. However, those either need an extra `Class<T>` argument or can potentially cause a type casting error.

Is there a way to create a function in a parent class such that an object of either parent or child type can return itself or an object of the same type?

Comment: Seems like you're trying to make a generic builder. This article explains a way to do it: https://vyazelenko.com/2012/03/02/recursive-generics-to-the-rescue/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The obvious solution to this issue is to just override every function and convert them into an object of the child type, but I don't want to do this every time I make a child class.

If you have a special method to create a new instance of the child type, you can reuse this in all your other methods. You'll still have to override this one method in each child class but it's better than overriding every method:

```
public abstract class Parent<T extends Parent<T>> {
  protected abstract T newInstance();

  public T doSomething() {
    T instance = newInstance();
    // do something with instance
    return instance;
  }

  public T doSomethingElse() {
    // do something with this
    return this;
  }
}

public class Child extends Parent<Child> {
  protected Child newInstance() {
    return new Child();
  }
}
```

`Child.doSomething` now returns a `Child` without having to override `doSomething`.

Comment: I notice that every time `doSomething()` is called, `newInstance()` in the `Child` class returns a new object. If I replaced the line `return new Child();` with `return this;`, would the function in `Parent` still work?

Comment: @ColePetersen: Yes, you can `return this;` without even calling `newInstance` if you simply want to modify the current instance. See the updated example with `doSomethingElse`.

Comment: In the `doSomethingElse` function, the compiler wants me to cast `this` to `T` or change the return type to `Parent<T>`. Which of these should I do @casablanca?

Comment: @ColePetersen: Casting is *generally* safe under this pattern but it is possible to come up with weird use cases that will break (such as if you do `ChildB extends Parent<ChildA>`). You can always add another abstract method that simply does `return this;` in every subclass and this will catch the weird use cases at compile time.